# Select all single quotes in regex field

Tags: regex

I have this field in my JSON data:

`"pinyin": "bei1 'ai1",`

I just want to select any single quote ' like the one before ai1;

I tried this

```regex
(?<="pinyin": "\w*)\'+(?!")
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/11954025

Comment: I'm still lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<="pinyin": "[\w\s]*)'(?!")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hljdS5/1). *Details*:

- `(?<="pinyin": "[\w\s]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `"pinyin": "` and then any zero or more word or whitespace chars
- `'` - a single quotation mark
- `(?!")`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match of there is a `"` char immediately to the right of the current location.